# Get current sound volume windows 8

Tags: c#, winapi

The result of the sound level is always 0, wether i have the sound muted or at max volume.

What is wrong ?

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hwo, out uint dwVolume);

public int GetCurrentSoundValue()
            {
                uint currentVolume;
                int result = waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, out currentVolume);
                return result;
            }
```

Comment: Don't you need to return currentvolume?

Comment: if i return currentvolume, the result is also always 4294967295. wether i mute it or max it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ever since Windows 7/Vista, microsoft changed the permissions to modify low level audio. Instead you have to use CoreAudio API. I can't provide too much info as I haven't really played around with it, but here's a link: [CoreAudio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Good luck!